# Why are default template arguments only allowed on class templates?

Tags: c++, templates, language-design, c++98

Why are default template arguments only allowed on class templates?  Why can't we define a default type in a member function template?  For example:

```
struct my_class {
  template<class T = int>
  void mymember(T* vec) {
    // ...
  }
};
```

Instead, C++ forces that default template arguments are only allowed on a class template.

Comment: For the first three posted answers, consider this example: `struct S { template <class R = int> R get_me_R() { return R(); } };` The template parameter can't be deduced from the context.

Comment: Good question. 3 people have already answered to say it "doesn't make sense", and they're all wrong in general. Function template parameters are *not* always deductible from the function call parameters. For example, if they were allowed I could write `template <int N = 1> int &increment(int &i) { i += N; return i; }`, and then `increment(i);` or `increment<2>(i);`. As it is, I have to write `increment<1>(i);`.

Comment: Actually, mine and AraK's examples can both be dealt with by overloading. litb's can't, I think, because the template parameter *might* be deduced or might be specified.

Comment: @Steve, hmm you can write `template<typename Iterator> void sort(Iterator beg, Iterator end) { sort(beg, end, std::less<Iterator>()); }` and write the three-args as an overload. I think it's done that way in today's `std::sort`. (aww, i should have passed `value_type` to std::less xD)

Comment: std::sort is done that way now, but your definition allows something that the current definition doesn't - specifying 2 (of 2) template parameters but only 2 (of 3) function call arguments. But I wrongly thought that means your example *can't* be done with overloads, actually it merely *isn't* done with overloads currently since the 2-template-param overload doesn't have a default value for its 3rd param. The example in the defect report can be done with overloads (I checked, finding a missing ; in the example text in the process).

Comment: @Steve: The missing semicolon is actually a new EOL operator overload to complement B. Stavtrup's "Overloading of C++ Whitespace" published in Journal of Object-Oriented Programming, April 1, 1992. (http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/papers.html)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

It makes sense to give default template arguments. For example you could create a sort function:

```
template<typename Iterator, 
         typename Comp = std::less<
            typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type> >
void sort(Iterator beg, Iterator end, Comp c = Comp()) {
  ...
}
```

C++0x introduces them to C++. See this defect report by Bjarne Stroustrup: [Default Template Arguments for Function Templates](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#226) and what he says

> The prohibition of default template arguments for function templates is a misbegotten remnant of the time where freestanding functions were treated as second class citizens and required all template arguments to be deduced from the function arguments rather than specified.
>
> The restriction seriously cramps programming style by unnecessarily making freestanding functions different from member functions, thus making it harder to write STL-style code.

Comment: @Arman, the defect report link contains the changes that are made to the working draft for C++0x and the discussions. Arguments neither deduced nor explicitly specified are obtained from default arguments. GCC4.4 supports default arguments for function templates in C++0x mode.

Comment: Nothing to do with the question or answer, but Herb Sutter called the upcomming standard C++11 after last saturdays meeting. I just read it today and feel like sharing :) http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2010/03/13/trip-report-march-2010-iso-c-standards-meeting/

Comment: and the obligatory follow up question... when is this expected to make it's way into other compilers :)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I had the same problem: no possibility to speficy the default type in a template function. I have solved by an explicit instantiation of the function on the default type (`double` in my case). Perhaps it is not "general", but is there any drawback with this practice? Thanks.

Comment: The following code fails to compile, with errors like `error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’`, any idea why:

`
    #include <array>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <functional>

    template<typename Iterator, typename Comp = std::less<Iterator> >
    void my_sort(Iterator beg, Iterator end, Comp c = Comp()) {
        std::sort(beg, end, c);
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        std::array<int, 5> ar{5,2,21,7,4};
        my_sort(ar.begin(), ar.end());
    }
`

Comment: @hazelnusse please make a new stackoverflow question for that. the compiler error in that snippet is orthogonal to this question I answered.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, while you are technically correct, most sorts don't compare iterators but instead the values pointed to by the iterators.  Changing `std::less<Iterator>` to `std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>` fixes the issue.

Comment: @hazelnusse ah I'm sorry I didn't notice the code you gave me was partly the code of my answer. Of course there was a technical error in my code. Fixed

Comment: Using modern C++  the template header can be simplified to just `template<typename Iterator, typename Comp = std::less<>>`.

Comment: Is your answer still valid with C++11 C++14 or C++17?

Answer (score 38):

To quote *C++ Templates:  The Complete Guide* (page 207):

> When templates were originally added to the C++ language, explicit function template arguments were not a valid construct.  Function template arguments always had to be deducible from the call expression.  As a result, there seemed to be no compelling reason to allow default function template arguments because the default would always be overridden by the deduced value.

Answer (score 18):

So far, all the proffered examples of default template parameters for function templates can be done with overloads.

AraK:

```
struct S { 
    template <class R = int> R get_me_R() { return R(); } 
};
```

could be:

```
struct S {
    template <class R> R get_me_R() { return R(); } 
    int get_me_R() { return int(); }
};
```

My own:

```
template <int N = 1> int &increment(int &i) { i += N; return i; }
```

could be:

```
template <int N> int &increment(int &i) { i += N; return i; }
int &increment(int &i) { return increment<1>(i); }
```

litb:

```
template<typename Iterator, typename Comp = std::less<Iterator> >
void sort(Iterator beg, Iterator end, Comp c = Comp())
```

could be:

```
template<typename Iterator>
void sort(Iterator beg, Iterator end, std::less<Iterator> c = std::less<Iterator>())

template<typename Iterator, typename Comp >
void sort(Iterator beg, Iterator end, Comp c = Comp())
```

Stroustrup:

```
template <class T, class U = double>
void f(T t = 0, U u = 0);
```

Could be:

```
template <typename S, typename T> void f(S s = 0, T t = 0);
template <typename S> void f(S s = 0, double t = 0);
```

Which I proved with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctype.h>

template <typename T> T prettify(T t) { return t; }
std::string prettify(char c) { 
    std::stringstream ss;
    if (isprint((unsigned char)c)) {
        ss << "'" << c << "'";
    } else {
        ss << (int)c;
    }
    return ss.str();
}

template <typename S, typename T> void g(S s, T t){
    std::cout << "f<" << typeid(S).name() << "," << typeid(T).name()
        << ">(" << s << "," << prettify(t) << ")\n";
}


template <typename S, typename T> void f(S s = 0, T t = 0){
    g<S,T>(s,t);
}

template <typename S> void f(S s = 0, double t = 0) {
    g<S,double>(s, t);
}

int main() {
        f(1, 'c');         // f<int,char>(1,'c')
        f(1);              // f<int,double>(1,0)
//        f();               // error: T cannot be deduced
        f<int>();          // f<int,double>(0,0)
        f<int,char>();     // f<int,char>(0,0)
}
```

The printed output matches the comments for each call to f, and the commented-out call fails to compile as expected.

So I suspect that default template parameters "aren't needed", but probably only in the same sense that default function arguments "aren't needed". As Stroustrup's defect report indicates, the addition of non-deduced parameters was too late for anyone to realise and/or really appreciate that it made defaults useful. So the current situation is in effect based on a version of function templates which was never standard.

Comment: @Steve: So the egg was running faster than chicken?:) interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Probably just one of those things. The C++ standardisation process runs slow in part so that people have time to realise when a change creates opportunities or difficulties elsewhere in the standard. Difficulties hopefully are caught by the people implementing the draft standard as they go along, when they spot a contradiction or ambiguity. Opportunities to allow things that weren't allowed before, rely on someone who wants to write the code noticing that it no longer needs to be illegal...

Comment: One more for you: `template<typename T = void> int SomeFunction();`.  The template parameter here is never used, and in fact the function is never called; the only place it is referred to is in a `decltype` or `sizeof`.  The name deliberately matches the name of another function but the fact it's a template means the compiler will prefer the free function if it exists.  The two are used in SFINAE to provide default behaviour where a function definition is missing.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, with all versions of Visual Studio you can convert this error ([C4519](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/190h9wbh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to a warning or disable it like so:

```
#ifdef  _MSC_VER
#pragma warning(1 : 4519) // convert error C4519 to warning
// #pragma warning(disable : 4519) // disable error C4519
#endif
```

See more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/190h9wbh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Note that, while this does disable the "default template arguments are only allowed on a class template" message, it doesn't actually make the template instantiation process *use* the provided value. That requires VS2013 (or any other compiler that has completed C++11 defect 226 "Default template arguments for function templates")

Answer (score 1):

What I use is next trick:

Lets say you want to have function like this:

```
template <typename E, typename ARR_E = MyArray_t<E> > void doStuff(ARR_E array)
{
    E one(1);
    array.add( one );
}
```

You will not be allowed, but I do next way:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyArray_t {
void add(T i) 
{
    // ...
}
};

template <typename E, typename ARR_E = MyArray_t<E> >
class worker {
public:
    /*static - as you wish */ ARR_E* parr_;
    void doStuff(); /* do not make this one static also, MSVC complains */
};

template <typename E, typename ARR_E>
void worker<E, ARR_E>::doStuff()
{
    E one(1);
    parr_->add( one );
}
```

So this way you may use it like this:

```
MyArray_t<int> my_array;
worker<int> w;
w.parr_ = &arr;
w.doStuff();
```

As we can see no need to explicitly set second parameter.
Maybe it will be useful for someone.

Comment: This is definitely not an answer.

Comment: @deadmg - can you explain why? We're not all C++ template gurus. Thanks.

Comment: This is a workaround which is pretty neat but it won't cover all the cases you might want. For example how would you apply this to a constructor?

Comment: @TiberiuSavin - if I understood you correctly, then you can do like this: template <typename E, typename ARR_E> worker<E, ARR_E>::worker(ARR_E* parr) { parr_ = parr; }. And then use it like this: worker<int> w2(&my_array);