# C++ template with default parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I try to use default parameters in my template, like this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename S, typename T=int> 
S myadd(T a, T b)
{
    S tmp = a + b;
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    float i = 5.1, j = 5.2;

    cout << myadd<int, int>(i, j);
    cout << myadd<float>(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Then g++ myadd.cpp

It shows error:

> default template arguments may not be used in function templates without -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x

Why does this happen?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand in that error message? What did you try to make this compile?

Comment: You don't know why? The why is because "default template arguments may not be used in function templates without -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x".

Comment: Just a wild guess, but are you compiling with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x?

Comment: Why would you want a default T in this case? T can be deducted from the parameters' types.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I just use g++ and  g++ myadd.cpp in a terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Default template arguments for function templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447458/default-template-arguments-for-function-templates)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extracted this answer from Stack Overflow question *[Default template arguments for function templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447458)*:

To quote C++ Templates: The Complete Guide (page 207):

> When templates were originally added to the C++ language, explicit
>   function template arguments were not a valid construct. Function
>   template arguments always had to be deducible from the call
>   expression. As a result, there seemed to be no compelling reason to
>   allow default function template arguments because the default would
>   always be overridden by the deduced value.

Read [the Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447458) to understand quite more. NOTE: the default parameter in a function template  C++ is a new feature in gnu++0x.