# Template usage in CUDA code

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to understand how template is being used here:

```
template <uint32_t N_ATOMIC=32>
struct ParallelCounter {
public:
  uint32_t count[N_ATOMIC];

   // spread the counts across the counter
  __device__ __host__ void set(uint32_t x) {
    for(int i=0; i < N_ATOMIC; i++) count[i]=x/N_ATOMIC;

  } 

};



#ifndef SPREAD
#define SPREAD 32
#endif
__device__ ParallelCounter<SPREAD> myCounter;
__global__ void initCounter() {
  int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

  if(tid == 0)
    myCounter.set(0);
}
```

All the examples on templates that I have seen so far have some variable in <  >  in first line above. But why we are having a constant uint32_t N_ATOMIC=32 here.  if it is a constant, how would the template be useful? It is fixed for a particular type. Am I right? Thanks

Comment: The same as any defaults, regardless of cuda, templates, whatever

Answer (score 1):

This question has nothing to do with CUDA.

If you define a template this way, it means that if you instantiate the template but don't provide that parameter specifically, it will [default to the value indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637220/c-template-with-default-parameters).  You can still instantiate the template with other values, to get different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that only typename can be used as a template parameter. A int const can also be a template parameter.

It's useful because this parameter can be determined in compile-time, rather than run-time. Earlier determination is helpful in generating more optimized run-time code.

In your particular case, the size of the struct `ParallelCounter` have to be determined during the compile-time. C++ won't accept a type whose size can not be determined until run-time.

If template is not used in your code, you may have to write a series of `struct ParallelCounter` and `void initCounter()` for different values of `SPREAD`