# Default template parameters: Why does the compiler complain about not specifying template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, default-parameters, template-argument-deduction

I have this code:

```
struct A{};

template<class T = A>
struct B {
    void foo() {}
};

B b; //Error: missing template arguments before 'b'
     //Error: expected ';' before 'b'
     //More errors
b.foo()
```

If I make `foo()` as a template function with the same template 'signature', the compiler doesn't complain about not specifying the template arguments:

```
struct A {};

struct B {
    template<class T = A>
    void foo() {}
};

B b; //OK
b.foo()
```

So why do I need to specify an argument for a template class with a default parameter, but not for a template function? Is there some subtlety I am missing?

The reason is because of template argument deduction failure for sure. But I want to know why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Default template arguments for function templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447458/default-template-arguments-for-function-templates)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct syntax is this ([demo](http://ideone.com/BBGF9)):

```
B<> b;
```

The default argument `A` is assumed for the class template `B`. The `<>` part tells the compiler that `B` is a class template and asks it to take the default parameter as the template argument to it.

Comment: I see. But why does the template function work without this: `b.foo<>()`?

Comment: My bad. Should have mentioned g++ 4.7.0 which has support for default template parameters for functions. So the code above definitely works. Try running with g++ 4.7.0.

Comment: @Nawaz: [Yes it does](http://ideone.com/RvAcN); you need C++11 for the default argument, but the function call is fine. Function templates can be called without function argument lists; that allows overload resolution to consider both template specialisations and non-template overloads.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Yup. I realized that C++03 doesn't allow default argument for function template. C++11 does, though.

Comment: Any reason why i don't need to do this: `b.foo<>()`? Is it because the deduction process is different in these two cases?

Comment: @badmaash: As Mike said in his comment : `"Function templates can be called without function argument lists; that allows overload resolution to consider both template specialisations and non-template overloads."`. That makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: @badmaash: function templates are different from class templates. They just are. They obey different rules and can be used differently.

Comment: My comment would make more sense if I'd written "without *template* argument lists"; shame I can't correct that now.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax, as Nawaz mentions already is:

```
B<> b;
```

The reason is that `B` is the template and `B<>` is the instantiation of the template with the default argument `A`. But you need the `<>` to differentiate when you want an instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to say that `B` is a template:

```
B<> b;
```

Even when you don't want to specify any of the arguments.

Comment: Actually you need `<>` to tell the compiler you don't want a template, but the instantiation of a template with the default argument. The syntax is correct though.