# Why are there two implementations of std::sort (with and without a comparator) rather than one implementation with a default template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, parameters, default

In my code I'm adopting a design strategy which is similar to some standard library algorithms in that the exact behavior can be customized by a function object. The simplest example is std::sort, where a function object can control how the comparison is made between objects.

I notice that the Visual C++ provides two implementations of std::sort, which naturally involves code duplication. I would have imagined that it was instead possible to have only one implementation, and provide a default comparator (using operator< ) as a default template parameter.

What is the rational behind two separate versions? Would my suggestion make the interface more complex in some way? Or result in confusing error messages when the object does not provide operator< ? Or maybe it just doesn't work?

Thanks,

David

Comment: "*I notice that the Visual C++ provides two implementations of std::sort, which naturally involves code duplication.*" Why would you think that? The obvious implementation is for the overload lacking a predicate argument to be implemented in terms of the overload taking a predicate argument (passing `std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>()` for said argument).

Comment: _"Why would you think that?"_ - I'm looking at the implementation of algorithm which ships with Visual C++ and seeing two seperate implementations.

Comment: That's a single, apparently poor implementation; I was picking on the word 'naturally', which is most certainly not accurate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because function templates are not allowed by the standard to have default type arguments.

[This, however, was amended in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2447556/726361), and now function templates can have default type arguments.

Comment: I'll mention that, while correct, this is now just an historical reason, because C++11 allows it.

Comment: Knowing next to nothing about templates in C++, are you not allowed to overload function templates?

Comment: @JAB yes you are, and that's encouraged over specialising them.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes yeah, I just wanted to make sure before I added that to the answeer.

Comment: So if you were using non-C++11 code, you could simply have the overloaded template with less template arguments wrap the one with more arguments? Last I checked, that's the general convention for languages that prefer overloading to utilization of default arguments.

Comment: @JAB That's exactly what there is: two overloads of `std::sort`.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes One does not appear to wrap the other though (but ultimatly they do both wrap a heap sort or insertion sort).

Answer (score 2):

Prior to C++11, a function template could not have default template arguments, and a template argument cannot be deduced from a default function argument, so there was no way to make this work.

In C++11, which supports default template arguments for function templates, you could use a single function template, but changing it now would break backwards compatibility with older C++ code that relies on the functions having a particular type.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think I'd rather avoid requireing C++11 support from my users so I guess I'll follow the STL model.

Comment: That's especially important if you are supporting Visual C++ (which you indicate in your question), because it does not yet support C++11's default function template arguments :-)

Comment: Ah, well, that settles it then :-)