# Default parameter and templates

Tags: c++, templates, default-value

Why does this function give me an error:

```
template < typename T >
T foo( T s = 0, const vector < T > &v)
{
    ...
}
```

> error: default argument missing for parameter 2 of ‘template summable sum(summable, const std::vector&)’

And why doesn't the following?:

```
template < typename T >
T foo( const vector < T > &v, T s = 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Can function default template parameter be put before non-default ones?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684954/can-function-default-template-parameter-be-put-before-non-default-ones)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Optional arguments must be the last. I.e. non-optional arguments cannot follow an optional one.

How would you call

```
T foo( T s = 0, const vector < T > &v)
```

with *just* a `v`, and no `s`?

How would the compiler spot this if

- `s` and `v` had the same type, or
- there was an overload of `foo` taking just a `const vector<T>&`?

Answer (score 2):

If argument has a default value, than all following arguments need to have default value as well.

Rationale is given in other answers, so I'll give you a quote from C++11 standard:

> **8.3.6 Default arguments [dcl.fct.default]**
>
> 4 (...) In a given function declaration, each parameter subsequent to a
>   parameter with a default argument shall have a default argument
>   supplied in this or a previous declaration or shall be a function
>   parameter pack.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments with defaults need to be the last arguments.  In the first, you have s with a default of 0, then v with no default.  You cannot have an argument with no default following an argument with a default.

How would you call such as argument using its defaults? `foo(/*default*/,vector)` ?