# Center text in fixed-width field with stream manipulators in C++

Tags: c++, string, stringstream, ostream, manipulators

I am refactoring some legacy code which is using `printf` with longs strings (without any actual formatting) to print out plain text table headers which looks notionally like this:

```
|  Table   |  Column  | Header  |
```

which are currently being produced like this:

```
printf("|  Table   |  Column  | Header  |");
```

I would like to produce the above with code to the effect of<sup>1</sup>:

```
outputStream << "|" << std::setw(10) << std::center << "Table"
             << "|" << std::setw(10) << std::center << "Column"
             << "|" << std::setw(9) << std::center << "Header"
             << "|" << std::endl;
```

which does not compile because `<iomanip>` has the stream manipulators `std::left`, `std::right` and `std::internal`, but does not seem to have any `std::center`. Is there a clean way to do this already in standard C++ libraries, or will I have to manually compute the necessary spacing?

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Even though this is more verbose than the C code, it will be less verbose in the long run because of the number of `printf` statements and the amount of infixed duplication in their strings. It will also be more extensible and maintainable.</sub>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a helper class that accomplish what you want:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template<typename charT, typename traits = std::char_traits<charT> >
class center_helper {
    std::basic_string<charT, traits> str_;
public:
    center_helper(std::basic_string<charT, traits> str) : str_(str) {}
    template<typename a, typename b>
    friend std::basic_ostream<a, b>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<a, b>& s, const center_helper<a, b>& c);
};

template<typename charT, typename traits = std::char_traits<charT> >
center_helper<charT, traits> centered(std::basic_string<charT, traits> str) {
    return center_helper<charT, traits>(str);
}

// redeclare for std::string directly so we can support anything that implicitly converts to std::string
center_helper<std::string::value_type, std::string::traits_type> centered(const std::string& str) {
    return center_helper<std::string::value_type, std::string::traits_type>(str);
}

template<typename charT, typename traits>
std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& s, const center_helper<charT, traits>& c) {
    std::streamsize w = s.width();
    if (w > c.str_.length()) {
        std::streamsize left = (w + c.str_.length()) / 2;
        s.width(left);
        s << c.str_;
        s.width(w - left);
        s << "";
    } else {
        s << c.str_;
    }
    return s;
}
```

It's used simply by calling `centered("String")`, like so:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "|" << std::setw(10) << centered("Table")
              << "|" << std::setw(10) << centered("Column")
              << "|" << std::setw(9)  << centered("Header") << "|"
              << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ah!! I like that. Very clever.

Comment: +1. I tested it here : [test-code](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f4728b397853f9c9d788f268d121b466)

Comment: Is this good only for C++0x? In MSVS 2010 I get "default template arguments are only allowed on a class template". According to [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447458/default-template-arguments-for-function-templates) this has been fixed in C++0x.

Comment: I get numerous errors with this under c++11, including the one about the default template arguments.

Comment: @jep: If you're getting a message about default template arguments, then you probably aren't compiling with C++11.

Comment: @KevinBallard: No, that's not the problem. My CMake flags include `-std=c++11`. And trust me, LOTS of stuff in my code wouldn't work if that was off. :)

Comment: @jep: The only other reason why you should be getting compiler errors is if you don't have all the right `#include`s.

Comment: If you edit your comment to include the `#include`s you included, I'll include them in my `#includes`.

Comment: @jep: Ok, I added the `#include`s.

Comment: Okay, my entire program is just that code plus a `main` func. I get: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zmRG3Xcf
Environment is cygwin 2.0.2 64bit/gcc 4.9.2/CMake 3.2.2.

Comment: Oh, and in CMakeLists.txt: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")`

Comment: @jep: Strange. It works perfectly fine in Clang. On line 24, try removing the default template parameter, so it's just `template<typename charT, typename traits>`. Does that work?

Comment: Yep, that did it! Wish I could give you more than one upvote for the effort. One last thing if you're up for it. clion gives the old red squiggle to line 21's `return center_helper<char>(str)` bit with the claim:
`Returning 'center_helper<char>' from a function returning 'center_helper': Class 'center_helper<char>' is not compatible with class 'center_helper' at line 21`
As it compiles fine, it seems like a bug I need to report to them. Do you have any advice on where it's going wrong so I can give a better report?

Comment: @jep: What happens if you change that line to say `return center_helper<std::string::value_type, std::string::traits_type>(str);`?

Comment: Also, I just edited my answer to remove the default template argument on line 24. It's not actually doing anything, I'm not really sure why I had it there in the first place, probably just because I was matching the template arguments to the `center_helper` class.

Comment: Right as rain now. Thanks, as that will help me give JetBrains a bit more info for my report.

Comment: @jep: Awesome. I'll edit the answer again to include that final change.

Comment: Proposal 1): pass by value and move into member for enhanced efficiency of the str argument of the center_helper template 2) Add explicit in front of the constructor to avoid unwanted automatic conversions happening. Like 
`explicit center_helper(std::basic_string<charT, traits> str) : str_(std::move(str)) {}`

Comment: @LilyBallard Greetings from the future (2019). I am having a hell of a time making this work in its own .h and .cpp files. Do you have these available in a github repository?

Comment: @hatinacat2000 I don't have this available anywhere outside of this SO answer. However I just tested and it still works. Make sure you're using C++11 or later. I've only tested single-file setups but I can't imagine why putting it in separate files wouldn't work.

Answer (score 27):

In C++20 you'll be able to use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) to do this:

```
outputStream << std::format("|{:^10}|{:^10}|{:^9}|\n",
                            "Table", "Column", "Header");
```

Output:

```
|  Table   |  Column  | Header  |
```

In the meantime you can use [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::format` is based on. {fmt} also provides the `print` function that makes this even easier and more efficient ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/j4rqEf)):

```
fmt::print("|{:^10}|{:^10}|{:^9}|\n", "Table", "Column", "Header");
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.

Answer (score 9):

There is no `std::center` manipulator. I am afraid you have to do it yourself. You could write a helper function to calculate the spaces given the width and the string, to reduce the efforts.

Here's a sample of what a helper function might look like. It needs some work to make it more efficient, etc.

```
string helper(int width, const string& str) {
    int len = str.length();
    if(width < len) { return str; }

    int diff = width - len;
    int pad1 = diff/2;
    int pad2 = diff - pad1;
    return string(pad1, ' ') + str + string(pad2, ' ');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you'll have to do it manually.  But it's not that
hard if you work with strings.  Something like:

```
std::string
centered( std::string const& original, int targetSize )
{
    assert( targetSize >= 0 );
    int padding = targetSize - checked_cast<int>( original.size() );
    return padding > 0
        ? std::string( padding / 2, ' ' ) 
            + original
            + std::string( targetSize - (padding / 2), ' ' )
        : original;
}
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This is just for the ones who don't need any additional changes in the code and not include any new libraries like me.

There are many answers given above which require new helper classes or additional libraries, but there is a simple hack instead which wont require any additional changes.
You can divide the width by 2 and add the setw() method on either side of the element to be printed.
As a solution to the question :

```
outputStream << "|" << std::setw(5) << "Table" << std::setw(5)
             << "|" << std::setw(5) << "Column" << std::setw(5)
             << "|" << std::setw(5) << "Header" << std::setw(5)
             << "|" << std::endl;
```

The above code will do the work.

Output:

```
|  Table   |  Column  | Header  |
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the NCURSES (#include <ncurses.h>) library... it's kinda funky and you have to add "-lncurses" to your compile command (gcc yourProgram.c/cpp -lncurses) and it'll work plus you can do colors and other 'cool' stuff (for CLI anyway).
just read the manual, centering stuff is pretty easy.
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/