# Function template: default type parameter

Tags: c++, function

I am working through the exercises in accelerated c++, and I am currently working on the chapter regarding generic functions. I came across an algorithm that I wanted to write that required, I think, the value_type of a given iterator. I came across this post [Default template arguments for function templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447458/default-template-arguments-for-function-templates) , which helped a lot, but I am wondering if my approach is correct. I don't want to get into a bad habit if that is indeed the case.

```
template <class ForwardIt, class BinaryOp = std::greater<std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type> >

ForwardIt maxInRange(ForwardIt begin, ForwardIt end, BinaryOp op = BinaryOp()) {
    // test here to reduce the loop count by 1

    if (begin == end)
      return begin;

    ForwardIt largest = begin;

    while (++begin != end)
        if (op(*begin, *largest))
            largest = begin;

    return largest;
}
```

One more question, sorry. How does the syntax regarding the BinaryOp type parameter work? I don't quite understand how calling a type as if it were a function produces a substitute-like effect. Thanks for your time. I really appreciate it.

Comment: The key is `<return type> operator()(some args...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BinaryOp op = BinaryOp()` is copy-initializing an instance of `BinaryOp` from a default-constructed temporary. The default template argument is `std::greater` which is the default type aliased by `BinaryOp`. Using `()` on any class type causes a constructor call. In this code you are creating a default parameter of type `std::greater`.

Next, where you are calling `op()`, you are actually invoking a member operator `bool operator()(const value_type&, condt value_type&)`. This allows `op` to act like a function object.