# C++ template constructor default arguments

Tags: c++, templates, default-value

In a very simple way. We have following code:

```
struct templateTest{
    struct {}m_none;
    template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
    templateTest(T1 arg1, T2 arg2=m_none, T3 arg3=m_none, T4 arg4=m_none){

    }
};

struct nonTemplate{
    nonTemplate(int arg1, int arg2=2, int arg3=3){}
};

int main()
{
    nonTemplate(5);
    nonTemplate(5,10);

    templateTest test2(5,10);
    templateTest test1(5);


    return 0;
}
```

What I would like to have is default constructor arguments in template class.

Default arguments work perfectly fine with `nonTemplate` class, but it's not that way with `templateTest` type. Error I have are following:

> C2660: 'templateTest::templateTest' : function does not take 2 arguments

for constructor called with 2 arguments

And for constructor called with one argument compiler wants to invoke copyConstructor and output is following:

> C2664: 'templateTest::templateTest(const templateTest &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const templateTest &'

Is there any way to achieve what I want on old C++ compilers, like msvc 2011?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447458/default-template-arguments-for-function-templates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
struct none_t {};
template <class T1, class T2=none_t, class T3=none_t, class T4=none_t>
templateTest(T1 arg1, T2 arg2=none_t{}, T3 arg3=none_t{}, T4 arg4=none_t{}){

}
```

you cannot deduce the template type arguments from the default arguments.  In essence, the template type arguments are deduced *before* default arguments are substituted.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e30a4d455cb95c3).

Comment: Yeah I know in fact, that It works, but it does not compile on msvc 2012 as there I cannot have default template types on class's members. What then?

Comment: @DawidPi Overloading.

Comment: @DawidPi create 4 overloads, with near-exact duplicates of the body and initializer list, each taking 1 2 3 and 4 arguments?  Get a new compiler?

Comment: That's the way I do this now in fact :) But I have 9 argument function, so you can just imagine how ugly code, becomes. Of course getting new compiler for whole company is impossible for me :) but still thanks :)

Comment: @DawidPi Boost has macros that they used to emulate variardics.  You could also write a function object (not a template function, because you cannot pass those around, and not a function, because they cannot represent more than 1 overload) and create an adapter that makes it variardic (writing the above 9+ overloads, dispatching more/fewer `none_t`s to the function object depending on passed-in arguments) if you find yourself doing it more than once.