# How to set a function as a default parameter?

Tags: c++11, templates, vector, iterator, default-value

I ran into a problem with setting a function as a default parameter.

The following code doesn't make a lot of sense. What I want to achieve can be done in many different ways. This code only describes the problem I ran into and wish to know how to fix it to work to my specifications.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int double_the_number(int x)
{
    return x * 2;
}

template<typename T, typename FunctionType>
std::vector<FunctionType> copy_with_criteria(T iter1, T iter2, FunctionType F(FunctionType))
{
    std::vector<int> new_vector;
    while(iter1 != iter2)
    {
        new_vector.push_back(F(*iter1++));
    }
    return new_vector;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {1,2,3,4,5};
    auto new_vector = copy_with_criteria(v.begin(), v.end(), double_the_number);
    for(int x : new_vector) std::cout << x << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

When the code above is ran, it will output `2 4 6 8 10`

What I want to achieve is if I call a function without specifying the criteria function `copy_with_criteria(v.begin(), v.end())` I want it to output `1,2,3,4,5`

That is, somehow I would like to set the function as a default parameter which is a type of elements inside some container (in this case `vector`) and which returns number that has been sent to it, like this (`TypeOfElements` is just an example of what type the default criteria function should be):

```
TypeOfElements default_function(TypeOfElements x) {
    return x;
}
```

I would not like to use any external libraries. Also I am working with c++11.

If anyone could help me with this problem I would be very grateful!

Thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default template arguments for function templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447458/default-template-arguments-for-function-templates)

Comment: Note your `copy_with_criteria` claims to return a `std::vector<FunctionType>` but contains a hard-coded `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Yes my mistake, I should have put that local vector with type of `FunctionType`

Answer (score 0):

Overload your function.

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type>
copy_with_criteria(T iter1, T iter2)
{
    return std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type>(iter1, iter2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your function as:

```
template<typename T, typename FunctionType = typename std::decay<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>::type>
std::vector<FunctionType> copy_with_criteria(T iter1, T iter2, FunctionType(*F)(FunctionType) = [](FunctionType v){ return v; }) {
    // ...
}
```

It works in C++11 as requested (see it on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d702042fa42d8226)).
The basic idea is that you can deduce `FunctionType` directly from the type of the iterators and not from the function `F`. Then you can give to `F` a default by using a lambda function that is nothing more than an identity function.

---

Otherwise you can simply overload `copy_with_criteria` as suggested by [aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43575841/4987285) (I'd rather go with his approach instead of using a default argument) or simply define a different function with a meaningful name that is explicit about your intention for you are not using criteria during that kind of copy.

**Edit**

As suggested by @aschepler in the comments, you can use `iterator_traits<T>::value_type` instead of `typename std::decay<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>::type` to avoid problems with some types.

Comment: Behaves dangerously if `T` is `std::vector<bool>::iterator`.

Comment: @aschepler Can you go a bit deeper with your comment? It sounds interesting, but I don't fully get it. Why does it behave dangerously in that case?

Comment: It returns a `std::vector<std::vector<bool>::reference>`, which becomes invalid if the original vector is modified or goes out of scope.

Comment: @aschepler Right, the reference, I didn't thought of it. Well, with a `std::enable_if_t` on the return type one can put a guard against it. Or use an overload as you suggested, that is the way suggested by the language. ;-)

Comment: Or use `iterator_traits<T>::value_type` to get `bool` instead of `std::vector<bool>::reference`.

Comment: @aschepler Indeed. Can I use your comments to integrate the answer (with credits)?

Answer (score 0):

Functions are the wrong thing to use here.  State can easily be useful.  You want to use a generic function object.  And deduce the return value.

In addition, using iterator ranges is questionable.  The next iteration of C++ range library is going to reduce that use.

While you want a C++11 solution, there is no reason to use the C++03/C++11 *style*.  Be forward looking.

So let us get started.

```
#include <iterator>
namespace notstd {
  namespace adl_helper {
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    template<class C>
    auto adl_begin( C&& )
    -> decltype( begin( std::declval<C>() ) );
    template<class T, std::size_t N>
    auto adl_begin( T(*)[N] )
    -> T*;
  }
  template<class C>
  using iterator_type=decltype(
    ::notstd::adl_helper::adl_begin( std::declval<C>() )
  );
}
```

This finds the iterator type of a container via calling `std::begin` in an ADL-enabled context.  This emulates what a `for(:)` loop does reasonably well.

```
namespace notstd {
  template<class C>
  using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<
    iterator_type<C>
  >::value_type;
}
```

now we can `value_type<C>` for some type `C` and get the type it contains.

```
namespace notstd {
  struct make_a_copy_t {
    template<class T>
    auto operator()(T&& t)const
    -> std::decay_t<T>
    {
      return std::forward<T>(t);
    }
  };
}
```

`make_a_copy_t` is a functor that copies stuff.

We are almost ready to solve your problem.

```
template<class Op=notstd::make_a_copy_t, class C,
  class R=decltype( std::declval<Op&>()(std::declval<notstd::value_type<C&>>()) )
>
std::vector<R>
copy_with_criteria(C&& c, Op op={})
{
  std::vector<R> new_vector;
  for (auto&& e:std::forward<C>(c))
  {
     new_vector.push_back( op(decltype(e)(e)) );
  }
  return new_vector;
}
```

and I believe this satisfies your criteria.

You may also need

```
namespace notstd {
  template<class It>
  struct range_t {
    It b = {};
    It e = {};
    It begin() const { return b; }
    It end() const { return e; }
    range_t( It s, It f ):b(std::move(s)), e(std::move(f)) {}
    range_t( It s, std::size_t count ):
      range_t( s, std::next(s, count) )
    {}
    range_t() = default;
    range_t(range_t&&)=default;
    range_t(range_t const&)=default;
    range_t& operator=(range_t&&)=default;
    range_t& operator=(range_t const&)=default;
    range_t without_front(std::size_t N)const {
      return {std::next(begin(), N), end()};
    }
    range_t without_back(std::size_t N)const {
      return {begin(), std::prev(end(),N)};
    }
    std::size_t size() const {
      return std::distance(begin(), end());
    }
    // etc
  };
  template<class It>
  range_t<It> range( It b, It e ) {
    return {std::move(b), std::move(e)};
  }
  template<class It>
  range_t<It> range( It b, std::size_t count ) {
    return {std::move(b), count};
  }
  template<class C>
  range_t<iterator_type<C&>> range( C& c ) {
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    return {begin(c), end(c)};
  }
}
```

which lets you do operations on subsections of a container as a range.

So suppose you want to take the first half of a vector of int and double it.

```
std::vector<int> some_values{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
auto front_half = notstd::range(some_values).without_back(some_values.size()/2);
auto front_doubled = copy_with_criteria( front_half, [](int x){return x*2;} );
```

and done.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7fd5ba66b5afe22).